# C multidimensional array size using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble using multidimensional arrays for a program. Essentially, the program uses scanf to read a user ID and a string of chars from a redirected file. the file format is a three digit user ID, a space, and a string of chars representing the answers to multiple choice problems on a test on each line, eg.

```
111 dabac
102 dcbdc
251 dbbac
```

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how many users there are, and I can't read the file data multiple times. I've tried using

```
for (lineNumber = 0; lineNumber != -1; lineNumber++)
{
int result = scanf("%d ", &data);
if (result == EOF)
  break;
for(i = 0; i < numProblems; i++)
{
  scanf("%c", &input);
}
```

to get the number of lines in the file, then set the size of the array. The array is then passed to another function that reads the data, using the same for loop but with

```
input = arrayName[numProblems][lineNumber];
```

in the second for loop. The issue I'm running into is that scanf can only read the data from the file once, and I can't store the data in the array until I initialize it, which requires me to know how many users there are.

The way I have it set up, the program can **either** find the number of lines(users) or store the data in the array (if I set the size to an arbitrary number), but not both.

I have to use scanf because the filename isn't constant (and also this is for a class... the professor requires scanf to be used), and I can't figure out how to get the number of lines in the file and still be able to read the data. If anyone knows of a workaround to either find the number of lines without using scanf, or to read the data twice, I would really appreciate some help. If it would help to post the entire program, I can do that as well.

Thank you,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.  I would recommend a linked list using structs, and keeping a count of what has been read so far.

If you really want to continue using arrays, allocate the array using malloc first, and then reallocate the array using realloc.  You'll have a running count of the size of the array for reallocation.

it should be something like this:

```
POINTER *array = realloc(orig_array_pt, size);
if (array  == NULL)
{
    // realloc failed
}
else
{
    orig_array_pt = array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the input is an actual file (and not a terminal or some other device), you can use `rewind(stdin);` to set the FILE pointer back to the beginning of the file...

Comment: how would I use this with scanf? It's an actual file, but I need to get the data through redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily scanf() will parse the whole line into multiple variables in one pass.  Try something more like

```
scanf( "%d %s", &uid, answers );
```

Just count the number of times you're able to successfully parse data out of the stdin and call that your lineNumber count ( if you even need to know the total number of lines ).

Comment: right, but how do I save the data into the array without initializing the array first?

Comment: malloc/realloc with a struct.  Or, if you're allowed to cheat, malloc "enough" lines up front to handle all the files you think you'll encounter ( or create them statically all at once ).  You said this is for homework, so I'm purposefully trying not to give you a finished answer.